# Fetch specific object from nested dictionary format data under a string form

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to fetch port value from cmd_resp.

```
    cmd_resp = '{ "toolkitStruct":{ "access_ctrl":{ "restricted":false, "disabled":false, "port":8001 }, "description":"EdgeX dev UI and API gateway (authenticated)", "label":"EdgeX API Gateway/UI" } }'
    output = cmd_resp.split('"port":')[1].split(',')[0]
    output = re.sub(r"[\}]", '', output).strip()
```

My way, I have achieved output = '8001' but can I get the same in more cleaner way? please suggest.
Additionally: And what, If need to save {"port":8001}?

Comment: `cmd_resp`is a json string. Parse it and then access it like a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re

> **(?<=...)** Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by
> a match for ... that ends at the current position. This is called a
> positive lookbehind assertion. (?<=abc)def will find a match in
> 'abcdef', since the lookbehind will back up 3 characters and check if
> the contained pattern matches. The contained pattern must only match
> strings of some fixed length, meaning that abc or a|b are allowed, but
> a* and a{3,4} are not.

```
output = re.search('(?<="port":)[0-9]*', cmd_resp)[0]
```